# How to simulate the click action in Query

Tags: jquery

```
$('.sale_type').click(function() {}
```

I have such a function,if I click the radio,the function will execute,but how to trigger the click if the radio is checked when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider moving the code that gets triggered when the radio is clicked in to its own function. That way, you don't need to simulate/trigger events to execute the function:

```
$('.sale_type').on('click', function() {
    doStuff();
});

$(document).on('ready', function() {
    if($('.sale_type').is(':checked')) {
        doStuff();
    }
});

function doStuff() {
   console.log('function code will be here');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) when dom is ready:

```js
$(":button").on("click", function() {
  alert("Ok");
});
//here check if radio is checked
if ($(":radio").prop("checked"))
  $(":button").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" checked />
<input type="button" value="test" />
```

**References**

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

**use:**

```
$('.sale_type').trigger("click")
```

Just remember you selected by class so all element with this class. Will have their onclick function (if any) triggerd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

- Check your element when page load

  $(document).read(function(){

  ```
      var checkElementChecked = $('.sale_type').is(":checked");       

      if(checkElementChecked === true)
      {
          $('.sale_type').trigger('click');
      }
  });
  ```